# Input z must be 2D, not 0D in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, contour

so i am trying to plot a contour of this function. Code follows:

```
#base packages
#import sympy as sp
#from sympy import *
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


x = np.reshape(np.array([0,0,0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.9,0.9,0.9]),(-1,1))
y = np.array([0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.])

def f(b0,b1,x,y):
    vec = [y[i]*np.log(1/(1+np.exp(-b0-b1*x[i]))) + (1-y[i])*np.log(1 - (1/(1+np.exp(-b0-b1*x[i])))) for i in range(len(y))]
    return np.sum(vec)


b00= np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
b11 = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(b00,b11)


contours = plt.contour(x, y, f(xv,yv,x,y), 3, colors='black')
plt.clabel(contours, inline=True, fontsize=8)

plt.imshow(f(xv,yv,x,y), extent=[-10,10, -10, 10], origin='lower',
           cmap='RdGy', alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar()
```

However, i get this error:

```
Input z must be 2D, not 0D
```

Any idea how i could fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You probably should tell us what programming language you are using! I think this is Python, and SO is far from a Python-only site!

Comment: Look at `f(xv,yv,x,y)` by itself (before calling `contour`).  Make sure it produces an array of values shaped like `x` or `y`.  Even though you pass it arrays, you return `np.sum(vec)`, which without any axis parameter returns a scalar - it sums **all** values.

Answer (score 0):

You function `f` is returning a number (0D - 0-dimensional), which you are using as the third argument of a function expecting a 2D array instead at that position (probably [`plt.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html), you did not include de real traceback).

The source code for that function calls the third argument `z`, hence the error message.